# CSS3 Transitions on reflow

Tags: css, css-transitions

Take this dom as an example.

```
<div id="container" style="transition: width 1s ease-in-out;">
  <div style="width: 400px; display: none;"></div>
  <div style="width: 200px;"></div> 
</div>
```

If I alternate which inner div is hidden, can I trigger the CSS3 transition (via reflow)?  If this were possible, I could add many inner divs and alternate between them smoothly without having to know what size they were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't think it's possible via CSS alone - transitions are not inheritable, so they would have to be applied to the nested elements in question, and a width transition couldn't be applied without the width anyway so e.g. the nested div would need it's `width` and `0` set to transition between them either on a hover or a JS click or some event

however I think I really am failing to understand the question;

```
#container div {transition: width 1s ease-in-out;}
```

would apply it to all child divs then you just toggle the display and width however you're thinking of doing it anyway?

Comment: I'm trying to transition b/t the two different sizes the container can have based on the contents that are visible.  When div #1 is shown, the #container will reflow to 400px wide when it is hidden #container will reflow back to 200pixels.  However, this can not be animated via css transitions (that Im aware of)

Comment: You can kind of do it,but I can't set up a pretty example.. display itself will not transition, so as soon as the CSS display: property would be toggled, the change would be instant, however how about toggling the width/height of an element, say on hover (I'm aware that there could be script involved here and in which case this can be scripted, but I take it you're talking theoretically?) - [**sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/peAmm/)  - it's not pretty as I've left 10px to be able to keep a hover on, but the theory might hold something?

Comment: LOL this is rather clever, I had to open it in FF to see the hovers are going a bit crazy here.  I guess the real answer is that I should transition the content in rather than just wapowing it on the page.  Thanks this is some cool css